# How to set default values (False) for a field in TransientModel- Odoo10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to set `False` value for `Import / Export` in General settings page of Odoo via my custom module. I tried below solutions, but no luck.

Here are my code:

Solution 1:

```
  <function id="default_module_base_import" model="ir.values" name="set_default" eval="('base.config.settings', 'module_base_import', False)"/>
```

Solution 2:

```
 module_base_import = fields.Boolean(string="Allow users to import data from CSV/XLS/XLSX/ODS files",default=False)
```

Solution 3:

```
@api.multi
def set_module_base_import_defaults(self):
return self.env['ir.values'].sudo().set_default(
    'base.config.settings', 'module_base_import',False)
```

Any solution?

Comment: It's like you want to uninstall Base import module, without having to go to general setting and do that?!!

Comment: As admin of so many Odoo systems i recommend two modules from [OCA's](https://github.com/OCA) [server-tools repository](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0): base_export_security and base_import_security_group. You will be more flexible by using them.

Comment: @EasyOdoo Yes, That is exactly i want.

Comment: @CZoellner, The repository that you suggested helped me, Thank you.